# Increase Podman memory limit

Tags: containers, podman

I am trying to build a large image with Podman. The build fails with

```
 Reached heap limit Allocation failed
```

error.

In docker I can avoid this by allocating more memory for docker engine in docker settings.

However, for Podman it doesn't seem to be so easy.
I tried to modify `~/.config/containers/podman/machine/qemu/podman-machine-default.json` and increase the memory, then run

```sh
podman machine stop
podman machine start
```

with no luck to solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: i am on podman 3.4, but i dont have podman folder under ~/.config/containers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So after playing around I found out that I was doing the right thing, but it is needed to change the memory amount in two places in the mentioned file (I changed only in one):

1. In the `"CmdLine"` section after `-m` flag
2. the `"Memory"` section itself

Answer (score 18):

The following commands are also very handy for quick resolution.

```
podman machine stop
podman machine set --cpus 2 --memory 2048
podman machine start
```

Source: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12713#issuecomment-1002567777

Comment: Thanks [@astromonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5795014/astromonkey) for the edit suggestion to 'Avoid using "rm" as it will delete all containers and it is better to adjust settings on existing machine'.
I adopted my response from
`> podman machine rm  
> podman machine init --cpus 2 --memory 2048`
to
`podman machine set --cpus 2 --memory 2048`